# Storing a DockPanel in a settings file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, settings, dockpanel

I am attempting to store a DevExpress DockPanel in a settings file. Everything appears to work in the save function, but when I go to load it upon starting the application, The Settings.Default.WebLayoutPanel variable is null: here is the save:

[image]

> Settings.Default.VisibilitySwitchesPanel = _visibilitySwitchesPanel;

and here is the load

> if (Settings.Default.WebLayoutPanel != null)
>
> {
>   _webLayoutPanel = Settings.Default.WebLayoutPanel; 
>   }

Any Ideas as to why it is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not save the `Control` instances directly into the application settings. It's a wrong way. You should save the specific settings of these controls using custom serializable wrapper and then restore these settings. Here is a useful links:

1. [Windows Forms - Creating and Persisting Custom User Settings in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29130/Windows-Forms-Creating-and-Persisting-Custom-User)
2. [Using Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750)

As for DevExpress DockPanels, when you want to save/restore the docking layout you should use the embedded save/restore functionality: [Saving and Restoring the Layout of Dock Panels](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1433)

Comment: You are correct, this is the wrong way to store my panels.  If you dont mind me asking why have you never asked a question on SO but answered so many?

Comment: @John: I like to answer on SO from time-to-time, but I have no questions yet which I can't answer myself... or Google can't ))

Comment: Well your help is appreciated even if we havent had the oppertunity to help you back.